# $scope variable not updating in each

Tags: angularjs

i am making a simple item calulation where i have item price, quantity and title stored in a array. I am calculating the total amount for each of the items:

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
<table>

<tr ng-repeat="itms in items"><td>{{itms.title}} <input type="text" ng-model="itms.quantity"/>{{itms.price}} - {{totalprice}}</td></tr>


</table>
```

in script:

```
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $log) {

$scope.items= [
{title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
{title: 'Polka Pots', quantity: 17, price: 6.95},
{title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 12.95}
]

//$log.log($scope.items[0].title);
//totalprice=quantity*price

$scope.totalprice=0;
for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
$log.log($scope.items[i].price*$scope.items[i].quantity);

//console.log($scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity);
$scope.totalprice = $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;

}


///$scope.totalprice = 

});
```

but the problem is that it is showing the calculated value of {{totalprice}} for only the last item, whereas the console shows the right calculation for each item in `$log.log($scope.items[i].price*$scope.items[i].quantity);`

Please tell me why in output it is showing only last calculation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you're recalculating & reassigning `$scope.totalprice` value, that's why last value gets assigned to `$scope.totalprice`

Comment: ok, pls give solution in code.

Comment: @user3450590 can you please mark the answers by clicking tick mark next to answers. you have poor history on marking answers

Answer (score 1):

You nee to have **`totalprice`** for each item defined.

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.items= [
{title: 'Paint Pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95,totalprice:0},
{title: 'Polka Pots', quantity: 17, price: 6.95,totalprice:0},
{title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 12.95,totalprice:0}
];
$scope.totalprice=0;
for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
$scope.items[i].totalprice = $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
}


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>

<tr ng-repeat="itms in items"><td>{{itms.title}} <input type="text" ng-model="itms.quantity"/>{{itms.price}} - {{itms.totalprice}}</td></tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. But just curious: can I not take out the value of $scope.totalprice WITHOUT adding it to the array? especially when the console `$log.log($scope.items[i].price*$scope.items[i].quantity);` throws the right values?

Comment: i dont get it, you dont need $scope.totalvalue

Comment: i am just saying that when I am getting the right values in `$log.log($scope.items[i].price*$scope.items[i].quantity)` , then why it is not reflectging in the {{totalprice}}. i think we could do someting like $watch to keep values updating, so somethimng similar, without adding `totalprice` inside the array.